# how i validate if the user has a token in localStorage

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

My app calls a Login api and returns me a token,i stored the token in localStorage so my problem is how i validade if the user has a token to do the login. what can i do to do that?

this is my login Page where i used to add the token to the localStorage

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { login } from '../services/login.services';

    function Login() {
     const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
     const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
     const history = useHistory();

    const loginHandler = async () => {
    const result = await login(email, password);
    console.log(result);

    localStorage.setItem('token', result?.response?.result?.token);
    localStorage.getItem('token');
};

return (
    <section className='layout'>
        <div className='wrp-login'>
            <div className='container'>
                <h1 color='white'>Login Page</h1>
                <div className='col-sm-6 offset-sm-3'>
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        placeholder='email'
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        className='input-wrapper'
                    />
                    <br />
                    <input
                        type='password'
                        placeholder='password'
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        className='input-wrapper'
                    />
                    <br />

                    <button onClick={() => loginHandler()} className='button'>
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
);}export default Login;
```

this is my Login Service wher i do the api call and return data

```
export const login = async (email, password) => {
try {
    const result = await fetch(
        'teste.com',
        {
            method: 'Post',
            body: JSON.stringify({ login: email, senha: password }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'default',
        },
    );

    return await result.json();
} catch (err) {
    return err;
}};
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: Well, for one thing you can capture errors using `try/catch`. You can test `result` to make sure its status code is 200 or another status code that represents success. You can not use optional chaining so that your code throws an error if the path to the token is invalid. If all of that passes, you need to decide what the app does next; we can't tell you.

Comment: i can create a file for file handling i think

Answer (score 0):

You can validate and redirect users by creating a wrapper for protected routes with react-router-dom to the login page if they don't have the token stored this way:

```
const ProtectedRoute = (props) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if (token == null) {
    return <Redirect to={Routes.LOGIN} />; 
  }

  return <>{props.children}</>;
};
```